# Shuffling an array using random-choice method instead of using Fisher-Yates

Tags: random, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

I am stuck with an apparently simple problem. I have written a subroutine that accepts an array of length `n` and another number `m` as inputs, and then outputs an array with size `m` which contains uniformly randomly chosen numbers from the original array. I can pass `replace=False` option, and then the numbers in the output array are always distinct given that there are no repetitions in the original array. My question is, can I use the same routine to randomly shuffle an array? At first sight this looks possible if I input `m=n`. The problem is that I am not sure whether this will output every possible permutation of the input array with equal probability (Although I would be surprised if it doesn't!). If that doesn't happen, I will write another routine for Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: Isn't that Fisher-Yates?

Comment: @KellyBundy : The random picking from the original array is achieved via `random_integer` routine whereas in Fisher-Yates one uses a slightly different picking. Isn't it?

Comment: What different picking?

Comment: @KellyBundy: I am referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this, when `numpy.random.shuffle` is right there. For that matter, `numpy.random.choice` is right there as well, and does what your existing function does.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : Who said I am using python? There is a very good reason for me to do this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Also, I did not add the tage `python`. Somebody else did.

Comment: That literally uses "random integer". Ok it doesn't say "routine", but does that matter?

Comment: Oh, well what *are* you using?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Fortran 95.

Comment: @KellyBundy: But there is a swapping right? Loop over i, generate a random integer from 0 to i, then swap etc. That looks operationally different than what I am doing although I expect both to produce the same result. I am not worried about efficiency here.

Comment: That swapping thing just makes it faster. With or without, you're picking one of the remaining numbers. Their original algorithm (also on that page) didn't even do that swapping. (Though I can't be totally sure about your code, as you're keeping it secret. (Then again I might not even be able to read it, don't know Fortran :-)).

Comment: I didn't post a code just to make this question language agnostic. Nothing secret here. If needed I can post it. However, I think you comment is helpful.